# Problema a cargar controles de Datatable en archivo php externo

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Tengo una pagina `propducto.php` la cual tiene una division `<div class="panel-body" id="muestraproductos">` donde cargo una tabla con datatable de manera dinámica. Es decir, en este div se muestra otra página que se llama `listaproductos.php`.

Esta acción se produce cuando doy click en un botón de mi página `producto.php`. La misma lo hago invocando a una función jQuery que está en un archivo llamado `script.js`.

El problema es que sí me carga la tabla con la información correcta pero los controles propios del datatable como el pagineo, la busqueda, la opciones de ordenar por cada columna, etc. no se visualizan.

Si cargo la tabla directamente en la pagina `producto.php` los controles del datatable se visualizan y funcionan correctamente el problema es cuando lo hago desde otro archivo y lo llamo utilizando un `.load()`.

Codigo del botón que invoca a la funcion jQuery que carga la página `listaproducto.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buscarproductos").click(function(){                       
    $('#muestraproductos').load('listaProductos.php') 
  });
});
```

Esot es `producto.php` (solo incluyo invocacion a funcion de jQuery que carga pagina `listaprodcuto.php`):

```
<div class="btn-group"> 
 <button type="button" name="buscarventasfechas" id="buscarproductos" 
 class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Realizar Búsqueda</button> 
</div>
```

Y esto es `ListaProducto.php`:

```
<?php include "class/var_config.php"; ?>
<?php
require_once("class/class.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link href="assets/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/datatables/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/datatables/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/datatables/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/table-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/script/validation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/script/script.js"></script>




  <?php




       ?> 
        <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>N°</th>
                                  <th>Código</th>
                                  <th>Producto</th>
                                  <th>Categoria</th>
                                  <th>Costo</th>
                                  <th>Existencia</th>
                                  <th>Tiene Iva</th>
                                  <th>Acciones</th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
<?php 

$tra = new Login();
$reg = $tra->ListarProductosFiltro();


if (is_array($reg))
   {  


$a=0;
foreach($reg as $element){  
$a = $a + 1
?>
                              <tr>
                                  <td><fixed layout table><?php echo $a ?></td>
                                  <td><fixed layout table><?php echo $element['codproducto']; ?></td>
                                  <td><fixed layout table><?php echo $element['producto']; ?></td>
                                  <td><fixed layout table><?php echo $element['nomcategoria']; ?></td>
                                  <td><fixed layout table><?php echo number_format($element['precioventa'], 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
                                  <td><fixed layout table><?php echo $element['existencia']; ?></td>
                                  <td><fixed layout table><?php echo $element['ivaproducto']; ?></td>
                                  <td><fixed layout table>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onClick="VerProducto('<?php echo $element['codproducto'] ?>')" data-href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-placement="left" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-id="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Ver Producto" title="Ver Producto"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>

<!--<a href="#" title="Ver Producto" onClick="VerProducto('')" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>-->

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Editar" onClick="actualizar('editproducto?codalmacen=<?php echo base64_encode($element["codalmacen"]) ?>')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onClick="eliminar('eliminar?<?php echo base64_encode('eliminar'); ?>&codproducto=<?php echo base64_encode($element["codproducto"]) ?>&tipo=<?php echo base64_encode("PRODUCTOS") ?>')" title="Eliminar" style="display: none" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a> 
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                <?php  }  ?>    
                              <?php  }  ?>  
                              </tbody>
                          </table>


<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--common script for all pages-->
    <script src="assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

    <!--script for this page-->
    <!-- Datatables-->
        <script src="assets/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/datatables/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>



        <script src="assets/js/jquery.app.js"></script>

 </html>
```

Comment: Es poco probable que una pagina (especialmente compleja) cargada dentro de otra vaya a presentar y funcionar bien, porque CSS y javascript mezclarán y habrán conflictos. Para insertar contenido de una pagina a otra se utilizan `iframe`, pero esto rara vez se ve bien y te recomiendo pensar otra forma de navegar por tu sitio web.

Comment: ¿Has intentado hacerlo con AJAX? yo tengo una implementación similar y lo hago con AJAX y funciona bien.